# It's time to come up with more topic challenges

Tags: discussion, weekly-topic-challenge

There are currently two remaining challenge topics (see [topic-challenge-proposal](/questions/tagged/topic-challenge-proposal)).  Let's all try to come up with some more.

(I realize this isn't properly a question...)